# How to use the Maven IEDriver library without the downloaded exe file

Tags: java, maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Quick question regarding where should I put the IEdriver.exe, if I use the following in the pom file

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-ie-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.46.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Do I need to paste the .exe driver in a specific path? or Maven will do this automatically and then I can access this path to define the path

```
               capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
                capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "10");
                System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", GET THE MAVEN PATH);
                driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);
```

Currently I have the IEDriver and the Chrome Driver in my repo, but I'm not sure if it is good to have both exe files there.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Place the IEDriver and the Chrome driver in a directory and then specify them in your program as below:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","File Path\\IEDriverServer.exe");
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "File Path\\chromedriver.exe");
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Comment: yes, I don't have any issue with that, basically my concern is:

is that the best way to do this? or is there an automatic way to download the drivers? currently I have both exe files in my github repo, and I'm doing something like this System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", Constant.vIEBrowserPath);

Answer (score 0):

Use the selenium standalone server plugin:

https://github.com/Ardesco/selenium-standalone-server-plugin

You add it to your POM like this:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.lazerycode.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>driver-binary-downloader-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.7</version>
        <configuration>
            <!-- root directory that downloaded driver binaries will be stored in -->
            <rootStandaloneServerDirectory>/my/location/binaries</rootStandaloneServerDirectory>
            <!-- Where you want to store downloaded zip files -->
            <downloadedZipFileDirectory>/my/location/zips</downloadedZipFileDirectory>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>selenium</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

It will download the driver binaries and set the system properties that Selenium is expecting.

You will want to define your own RepositoryMap.xml that details which driver binaries to download.

There is a working example here:

https://github.com/Ardesco/Selenium-Maven-Template